# MySQL stored procedure return variable values from seconds query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SET @v1 = '';
SET @v2 = '';

SET @Query = CONCAT('SELECT sum(colName1), sum(colName2) INTO @v1, @v2 FROM tableName WHERE id=1 ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @Query = CONCAT('SELECT id, name,',@v1,' as value1, ',@v2,' as value2 FROM tableName WHERE id=1 ');
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

While reading values the throw an Exception - **Column 'value1' does not belong to table.**

How can I get the value of @v1 and @v2.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **@v2 has null** value that why the stored procedure gives error.